# how to return new input value

Tags: javascript, html

i would like to replace my old input value (ancien_tel) by (nouveau_tel) to reformat my phone number on blur i missing something to return the value into my input text box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
        function reformatter() {
            var ancien_tel = document.querySelector("#telephone").value;

            var nouveau_tel = "(" + ancien_tel.substring(0, 3) + ") " + ancien_tel.substring(3, 6) + "-" + ancien_tel.substring(6).value;
            ancien_tel = nouveau_tel;

        }   
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Telephone:<br>
    <input type="text" id="telephone" onblur="reformatter()" maxlength="10">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just reassign the value property

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  doing

```
ancien_tel = nouveau_tel
```

, do:

```
document.querySelector('#telephone').value = nouveau_tel
```

`ancien_tel`'s value is copied from the `#telephone` element's value, it does not refer to what's inside the `#telephone` element.
A bit less verbose code could be something like:

```
function reformatter() {
  const telephone = document.querySelector("#telephone");

  const ancien_tel = telephone.value;
  const nouveau_tel = "(" + ancien_tel.substring(0, 3) + ") " + ancien_tel.substring(3, 6) + "-" + ancien_tel.substring(6).value;
  telephone.value = nouveau_tel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**All you need to change the reformatter function**

```js
function reformatter() {
        var ancien_tel = document.querySelector("#telephone").value;

        var nouveau_tel =
          "(" +
          ancien_tel.substring(0, 3) +
          ") " +
          ancien_tel.substring(3, 6) +
          "-" +
          ancien_tel.substring(6);

        document.querySelector("#telephone").value = nouveau_tel;
}
```